# Display customer group ID on page with all caches enabled

Tags: magento2, customer, cache, full-page-cache, customer-group

What's the best way to display the current customer's group id on the page when all caches are enabled including full-page cache.

I did think of potentially using JS and KO but it didn't look like the customer group is in
Magento_Customer/js/view/customer

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom module:
   First, create a custom module by following Magento 2's module creation process. Create the necessary files and directories such as `registration.php`, `etc/module.xml`, and `etc/events.xml`.
2. Observer for layout generation:
   In your custom module, create an observer class that listens to the `layout_generate_blocks_after` event. This event is triggered after the layout blocks are generated. In your observer class, you can retrieve the current customer's group ID and add a custom block to the layout.

```php
// File: Vendor/Module/Observer/LayoutGenerateBlocksAfterObserver.php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class LayoutGenerateBlocksAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $layout;
    private $customerSession;

    public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout, CustomerSession $customerSession)
    {
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $customerGroupId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
        
        $block = $this->layout->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::class,
            'custom_block',
            ['data' => ['customer_group_id' => $customerGroupId]]
        );

        $this->layout->addBlock($block);
    }
}
```

3. Modify block template:
   Create a template file for the custom block where you can display the customer group ID. In the example below, we'll assume the template file is `customer_group_id.phtml`.

```html
<!-- File: Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/customer_group_id.phtml -->

<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template */
/** @var $customerGroupId int */
?>

<p>Customer Group ID: <?php echo $customerGroupId; ?></p>
```

4. Update cacheable metadata:
   To ensure proper caching behavior, update the cacheable metadata for the custom block. This will make the block cache vary based on the customer group ID. Modify your observer class as follows:

```php
// File: Vendor/Module/Observer/LayoutGenerateBlocksAfterObserver.php

use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;

class LayoutGenerateBlocksAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $layout;
    private $customerSession;
    private $cacheTypeList;

    public function __construct(
        LayoutInterface $layout,
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
    ) {
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $customerGroupId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();

        $block = $this->layout->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::class,
            'custom_block',
            ['data' => ['customer_group_id' => $customerGroupId]]
        );

        // Set cache tags or cache keys based on customer group ID
        $block->setCacheTags(['CUSTOMER_GROUP_' . $customerGroupId]);
        $block->setCacheKey('CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID_' . $customerGroupId);

        $this->layout->addBlock($block);

        // Add the custom cache
```